# perturbation of trace norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, perturbation-theory

The definition of trace norm is the summation of singularities of that matrix. I need to calculate the trace norm of matrix with the form
                                   $$A = I + r$$
where the elements in r are much smaller than identity. Since I know there is perturbation theory of eigenvalue problem, I am wondering if there is similar formula for the perturbation of trace norm?

Comment: By "singularities of a matrix" I assume you mean the singular values. I searched for "singular values perturbation" and the first hit was this: [Perturbation Theory for the Singular Value Decomposition](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/552/4/CS-TR-2539.pdf). Probably it has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul!, that could be helpful. I will take a look.